# Start of an ATM program

Tags: python, beginner

I'm learning Python and have made this start of a ATM program, I'm very new to this so please be gentle..

Is there a better way to rewrite this?

```
CHECKING_BALANCE = 4000
SAVINGS_BALANCE = 1000

def welcome_screen():
    print """
    Welcome to the Bank of Bam!
    To continue please follow the instructions:
       Press 1 for Checking Account 
       Press 2 for Savings Account
       Press 3 for Balance Inquiries
       Press 4 to return card and exit
    """
    choice = int(raw_input("> "))
    if choice == 1:
        checking_account()
    elif choice == 2:
        savings_account()
    elif choice == 3:
        balance_inquiries()
    else:
        print "Exiting..."

def checking_account():
    print "You have $%i available" % (CHECKING_BALANCE)
    print """
    What would you like to do:
    [W]ithdrawl
    [D]eposit
    [T]ransfer funds
    """
    choice = raw_input("> ")
    if choice == "W":
        withdraw_funds()
    elif choice == "D":
        deposit_funds()
    elif choice == "T":
        transfer_funds
    else:
        print "Invalid input.."

def savings_account():
    print "You have $%i available" % (SAVINGS_BALANCE)
    print """
    [W]ithdrawl
    [D]eposit
    [T]ransfer
    """
    choice = raw_input("> ")
    if choice == "W":
        withdraw_funds()
    elif choice == "D":
        deposit_funds()
    elif choice == "T":
        transfer_funds()
    else:
        print "Invalid input.."

welcome_screen()
```

Example of usage:

```
    Welcome to the Bank of Bam!
    To continue please follow the instructions:
       Press 1 for Checking Account
       Press 2 for Savings Account
       Press 3 for Balance Inquiries
       Press 4 to return card and exit

> 1
You have $4000 available

    What would you like to do:
    [W]ithdrawl
    [D]eposit
    [T]ransfer funds

> Traceback (most recent call last): #<= CRTL - C
  File "atm.py", line 58, in <module>
    welcome_screen()


C:\Users\Justin\MyScripts>python atm.py

    Welcome to the Bank of Bam!
    To continue please follow the instructions:
       Press 1 for Checking Account
       Press 2 for Savings Account
       Press 3 for Balance Inquiries
       Press 4 to return card and exit

> 2
You have $1000 available

    [W]ithdrawl
    [D]eposit
    [T]ransfer

> Traceback (most recent call last): #<= CTRL - C
  File "atm.py", line 58, in <module>
    welcome_screen()
  File "atm.py", line 17, in welcome_screen
    savings_account()
  File "atm.py", line 48, in savings_account
    choice = raw_input("> ")
EOFError
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! Good job on your first answer. Perhaps you could improve your post by adding a sample session with a user using this program.

Comment: @SirPython I can do that, give me a second

Comment: @SirPython No they're CTRL - C tracebacks, I'm just looking for any better syntax in what I've written so far, this isn't completely finished (obviously) but I'm new and am very interested in learning

Answer (score 1):

The main thing I would say here is that you have 2 nigh identical functions apart from the balance being passed to them. Instead of `checking_account` and `savings_account` being different functions, make a single `account_interaction` function that takes an argument which you can then pass to the choden function.

```
def account_interaction(account):
    print "You have $%i available" % (account)
    print """
    What would you like to do:
    [W]ithdrawl
    [D]eposit
    [T]ransfer funds
    """
    choice = raw_input("> ")
    if choice == "W":
        withdraw_funds(account)
    elif choice == "D":
        deposit_funds(account)
    elif choice == "T":
        transfer_funds(account)
    else:
        print "Invalid input.."
```

Ideally `account` would be a class, or at least a dictionary that contains multiple relevant values (ie. type, amount, account holder), either of these makes it easier to pass them around functions like this.